# Making an array of object a value of a object in Array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays of objects. example

```
 data1 = [{
     foo: '2',
     box: 'yes',
     id: '1234'
 }, {
     foo: '34',
     box: 'no',
     id: '1235'
 }];

 data2 = [{
     key: 'value',
     key: 'value',
     id: '1234'
 }, {
     key: 'value',
     key: 'value',
     id: '1235'
 }];
```

I need it like this based on matching id value :
each obj has a unique key id, that much the second array.

```
finalData = [{
    foo: '2',
    box: 'yes',
    id: '1234',
    key: 'value',
    key: 'value'
}, {
    box: '34',
    box: 'no',
    id: '1235',
    key: 'value',
    key: 'value'
}];
```

basically merging the two arrays of objects based on key id .

Comment: Thanks,  that works perfectly fine.   what if on the objects I want to keep the key names that match but has a different value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.assign` for this so that you can combine the array with the common `id` value, use `find` having condition that compares the `id` of both the objects.

```js
var data1 =[ {foo:'2',box:'yes',id:'1234'},{foo:'34',box:'no',id:'1235'} ]; 
var data2 =[{key:'value',key2:'value2', id:'1234'},{key:'value',key2:'value2', id:'1235'}];

data1.map(x => Object.assign(x, data2.find(y => y.id == x.id)));

console.log(data1);
```

> Since you have same key name multiple times which is ignored by the
>   JSON object so I have taken a new property name `key2` for this
>   example.

Comment: Don't use `map` unless the mapped array is used. Otherwise, use `forEach`. Your answer also mutates the original objects in `data1`.

Answer (score 3):

building on @Ankit answer, you can use the spread operator too !!
something like this

```js
var data1 =[ {foo:'2',box:'yes',id:'1234'},{foo:'34',box:'no',id:'1235'} ]; 
var data2 =[{key:'value',key2:'value2', id:'1234'},{key:'value',key2:'value2', id:'1235'}];

const arr = data1.map(x => ({ ...x, ...data2.find(y => y.id == x.id)}));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) of array and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const data1 = [{foo: '2',box: 'yes',id: '1234'}, {foo: '34',box: 'no',id: '1235'}],
data2 = [{key: 'value',key1: 'value',id: '1234'}, {key: 'value',key1: 'value',id: '1235'}];
  
  let result = data1.reduce((r,{id,...rest})=>{
     let find=data2.find(o=>o.id==id);
     if(find){
        r.push(Object.assign(rest,find));
     }
     return r;
  },[])
  
  console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative to achieve this:

- Iterate over first array and create a new `Map` object where ids will be used as keys and relevant object as its value.
- Iterate over second array and update corresponding objects with same ids  using `Object.assign()` in `Map` object.
- Return an array of updated objects in `Map` object.

**Demo:**

```js
let data1 = [{foo: '2', box: 'yes', id: '1234'}, {foo: '34', box: 'no', id: '1235'}],
    data2 = [{key1: 'value', key2: 'value', id: '1234'}, {key1: 'value', key2: 'value', id: '1235'}];

let merge = (d1, d2, m = new Map(d1.map(o => [o.id, o]))) => (
              d2.forEach(o => m.set(o.id, Object.assign(m.get(o.id), o))),
              [...m.values()]
            );
            
console.log(merge(data1, data2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`Default Function Parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)